# conditional statement for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, conditional-tags, conditional-content

Struggling to find out how to achieve this, if it is at all possible. The equivalent of `is_category` but for a custom taxonomy I've set up. The taxonomy category if which being `Taxonomy Name` with 2 taxonomies: `Taxonomy One` and `Taxonomy Two`. But this:

```
<?php if ( has_term('taxonomy-one' ) ) {?>
    <div class="test" style="color: red"><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></div>
<?php } elseif ( has_term('taxonomy-two' ) ) {?>
    <div class="test" style="color: green"><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for this either so I'm not at all sure if it's possible, I'm hoping so though, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you shouldn't use negation in your conditions... If you check `! is_tax...` it will be true not only for other taxonomy pages, but also for singular pages, and any other...

So it should look like this:

```
<?php if ( is_tax('taxonomy-name','taxonomy-one' ) ) {?>
    <div class="test" style="color: red"><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></div>
<?php } elseif ( is_tax('taxonomy-name','taxonomy-two' ) ) {?>
    <div class="test" style="color: green"><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

And about lack of documentation... I have no idea where have you looked for, but there is codex page for `is_tax`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax ;)

PS. If you want to check if given post is assigned to term, then you should use [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function.

Comment: thanks for that! I have read that in the codex before, but I'm not actually looking to put this code in a taxonomy archive, but in a custom post type archive that I have added the custom taxonomies too :) I have tried the above code you suggested before as well and it didn't work :(

Comment: `is_tax` tells you if it's taxonomy archive. Custom post type archive is not a taxonomy archive (like posts index is not category archive)... So I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve...?

Comment: ah right, I didn't realise that, I'm new to taxonomies, apologies. What I was trying to achieve was to check if the post was in one taxonomy or the other. If in one the text in the post archive will be red if in the other the text in the post archive will be green.

Comment: No problem. You should use `has_term` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) then.

Comment: I've edited my question with the `has_term` still doesn't seem to work though, nothing showing up at all?

Comment: What is `taxonomy-one` in your code? Is it term or your custom taxonomy name?

Comment: it's the name of the term

Comment: You mean slug? And what is the name of that taxonomy?

Comment: yes the slug, the name being 'Taxonomy One'

Comment: And what is the name of this custom taxonomy? (not term)

Comment: the name of that taxonomy being 'Taxonomy Name' with the slug 'taxonomy-name'

Comment: OK, so try `has_term('taxonomy-one', 'taxonomy-name')`

Comment: voila!! that's worked, thanks so much for that, much appreciated.